# Second moment method

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose for a sequence of random variables $(X_n)_n$we know $E(X_n)\rightarrow c$, $c$ a constant, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \text{Var}(X_n)<\infty$. Then $X_n\rightarrow c$ a.s is the claim.

By Chebyshev inequality, we know $P(|X_n-E(X_n)|\geq\varepsilon)\leq\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}\text{Var}(X_n)$ for every $n$. By assumption, 
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X_n-E(X_n)|\geq\varepsilon)\leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \text{Var}(X_n)<\infty$. So by Borel Cantelli Lemma, we have $P(|X_n-E(X_n)|\geq \varepsilon\ \text{for infinitely many} \ n)=0$, which means that we have $P(|X_n-E(X_n)|\leq \varepsilon\ \text{for infinitely many} \ n)=1$. Now for every $\omega$ in the above set, we can choose a natural number $n_0(\omega)$ s.t. $\forall n\geq n_0(\omega):|X_n(\omega)-E(X_n)|\leq \varepsilon$. Since the sequence $|X_n(\omega)-E(X_n)|$ is bounded, $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|X_n(\omega)-E(X_n)|\leq\varepsilon$ (We don't know a priori, if the sequence converges, so we have to use the lim sup). Letting $\varepsilon\downarrow 0$, $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|X_n(\omega)-E(X_n)|=0$, but this automatically implies $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|X_n(\omega)-E(X_n)|=0,$ since the sequence is bounded from below by $0.$ 
$(0\leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}|X_n(\omega)-E(X_n)|\leq \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|X_n(\omega)-E(X_n)|=0)$.

Thus $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X_n(\omega)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} E(X_n)=c$.

Is this proof rigorous?

Comment: Yes, except the step "which means that we have $P(|X_n-E(X_n)|\leq \varepsilon\ \text{for infinitely many} \ n)=1$" which should read "which means that we have $P(|X_n-E(X_n)|\leq \varepsilon\ \text{for every} \ n\ \text{large enough})=1$".